network Routing
Trying to use IPtables to rout traffic between my intenretal network card and my wifi USB adaptor or my USB to network adaptor.
My ubuntu latest edition find these item but when i run ifconfig it will only see loopback and on or the other at once, not both items. Ubuntu seems to like 1 primary connected Device and thatch it. Does help if you want to setup basic routing between multiple NICs.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Wrong tool! Use ip route to set up your routing table.  man ip ip-route.  Routing decisions are made based on the network part of the IP address (IP ANDed with netmask)
